# Graph and Dijkstra infinite loop?

Tags: java, graph

So I creating a minecraft plugin where I am in need of a graph to create a navigation system. I researched a bit and found out that I should be able to use Dijkstra, but I have a problem. When searching for the shortest path I am sometimes getting an infinite loop(not always, it usally works the first 2-3 runs but after that it goes into the loop).

When the player wants to get to a destination I search for the closest vertex and use computePaths with that vertex as parameter. When I then run the getShortestPathTo it sometimes gets stuck in an infinite loop and I run out of memory(which makes sence since im adding the same vertexes to the list). Can you see why it is getting stuck? As far as I knew Dijkstra should be able to handle going from A node to B node and from B node to A node right?

Below is my code:

```
public class Dijkstra {
    public static void computePaths(Vertex source) {
    source.minDistance = 0.;
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    vertexQueue.add(source);

    while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

        // Visit each edge exiting u
        for (Edge e : u.adjacencies) {
            Vertex v = e.target;
            double weight = e.weight;
            double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
            if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
                vertexQueue.remove(v);
                v.minDistance = distanceThroughU;
                v.previous = u;
                vertexQueue.add(v);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target) {
    List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous) {
        path.add(vertex);
    }
    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}
}
```

and the vertex class:

```
public class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
{
    public final String name;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;
    public Location location;
    public Vertex(String argName) { name = argName; }
    public Vertex(String argName,Location l) { name = argName; location = l;}
    public String toString() { return name; }
    public int compareTo(Vertex other)
    {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

}
```

When first the plugin is enabled I load all the vertexes from a config file looking something like this(It is the test one i am using)

[image: Config file]

I am adding vertexes and edges here(not sure if relevent but thought it might be?):

```
public void loadAllVertex() {
    ConfigurationSection section = nodeConfig.config.getConfigurationSection("nodes");
    for (String key: section.getKeys(false)) {
        String locationString = nodeConfig.getString("nodes." + key + ".location");
        if (locationString == null)
            return;
        String[] locationSplit = locationString.split(",");
        if (locationSplit.length <=1) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Location is not specified correctly in nodes.yml");
            return;
        }
        Location l = new Location(Bukkit.getWorlds().get(0),Integer.parseInt(locationSplit[0]),Integer.parseInt(locationSplit[1]),Integer.parseInt(locationSplit[2]));
        Vertex tmpVertex = new Vertex(key, l);
        allNodes.add(tmpVertex);

    }

    for (Vertex v : allNodes) {
        String path = "nodes." + v.name + ".connectedTo";
        List<String> connectedTo = nodeConfig.getStringList(path,true);
        List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String sideNodeName : connectedTo) {
            Vertex vertexCon = GraphUtils.getVertexByName(allNodes, sideNodeName);
            if (vertexCon == null) {
                log.warning("The '" + sideNodeName + "' node is not defined");
                return;
            }
            //A.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(M, 8) };
            edges.add(new Edge(vertexCon,vertexCon.location.distance(v.location)));
        }
        Edge[] arrayEdges = new Edge[edges.size()];
        arrayEdges = edges.toArray(arrayEdges);
        v.adjacencies = arrayEdges;
    }

}
```

Comment: To confirm your supposition: **Yes**, Dijkstra also works on cyclic graphs. It works because once a node has been **settled**, its optimal distance is known and can not be improved thus Dijkstra will not add it to the queue again. And the algorithm will always for sure settle one node in each round.

Comment: Alright thanks @Zabuza, but in what circumstances can you end Up with a  infinite loop ?

Comment: Only if you have an implementation error (even for negative edge weights it terminates, however the result then is simply wrong). I did not take a look at your code close, thus only a comment. You should try to debug the programm, step by step, maybe on a very small example graph (where you can confirm if a specific step is correct or not). You need to enclose the error.

Comment: Regarding the infinite loop at getShortestPathTo()... Maybe vertex is never null? Debug your vertex = vertex.previous assignement to see what's happening. Also take a look to the other possible infinite loop: 
```
while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
```

Comment: Not really related to your question, but are you sure you want to use Dijkstra ? It can be a really greedy algorithm if your graph gets big.

Comment: Which other options would you recommend ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think i found the error, so I never had any loops the first time I ran the compute path and findshortestpath so I finally figured out that I could not be resetting things correctly(should have been obvious I know) - I didn't update the vertexes afterwards. So I added a method to reset the mindistance and previous attributes and this seems to have done the trick.